With Visual Studio, how to overwrite IIS packages?
We are four developers in my team ; we are working on the same server, each one having its own folder with its own version of the code.
We use a publish profile with the publish method set to Package, aka IIS Package.
When there was only one developer who published using this profile, the package had a size of roughly 60MB, even if he published multiple times. But when other developers started to publish, the package size was incremented for every developer - two developer : 120MB ; three developpers : 180MB...
When I look into the generated archive, there is a folder for each developer, each containing the website :

We use Visual Studio to make the package. It seems that it adds every new folder in the archive... how to force it to overwrite the package every time ?
